# Grails- Spring Web Flow -How to redirect to a page?

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

I'm using Webflow. I want to redirect to my homepage if the user click "no" on the first stage flow. How can I do it without include the homepage as part of my stages/steps?

```
    def redesignSignup = {
        redirect(action: "signupRedesign")
    }
    def signupRedesignFlow = {
        start {
            on("yes").to "startAccount"
            on("no"){redirect(controller: "home", action: "index")}
        }
        startAccount{
//          render(view: "startAccount")
            on("next"){}.to"connectPeople"
            on("back"){}.to"start"
        }
        connectPeople{
            on("next"){}.to"followCompanies"
            on("back"){}.to"startAccount"
        }
}
```

In the above code I get some of the following errors:
198 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter | 63 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter | 189 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter | 63 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter | 1145 | runWorker . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor | 615 | run in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker ^ 745 | run . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread urlJSON - - > ip-api.com/json/192.168.110.38

Comment: What error do you get? Include that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def signupRedesignFlow = {
    start {
        on("yes").to "startAccount"
        on("no").to("finish")
    }
    startAccount{
        on("next"){}.to"connectPeople"
        on("back"){}.to"start"
    }
    connectPeople{
        on("next"){}.to"followCompanies"
        on("back"){}.to"startAccount"
    }
   finish{
       redirect(controller: "home", action: "index")
  }
}
```